# Explaining NFA in words

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

I have an NFA, and the question I am asked is :

Let  <  < . Now in simple English, express the language of the NFA to explain what type of strings are accepted by it.

In simple English, my answer is

The NFA accepts strings over alphabet {a, b, c} such that the last symbol appears twice.

Which I know is correct, however my problem lies in the question where "a < b < c". How does this affect my NFA and is my answer still correct? My answer seems really short for 6 marks.

Comment: Your description is wrong since, for example, aca is not recognized by your automaton. Also, even if we can guess that it is $q_0$, you should indicate clearly what is the initial state.

Comment: What do you mean by $a < b < c$? It's a notation I'm unfamiliar with in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automaton accepts all non-empty strings in which the last symbol $\sigma$ appears at least twice, and all symbols appearing between its penultimate appearance and its last appearance are smaller than $\sigma$.